# How to solve the electric potential due to a charge distribution using fast Fourier transforms

Tags: potential, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform

I'm writing a toy program to simulate 2D wave functions. I'm using a split-operator method to solve the Schrödinger equation and have no problems with arbitrary potentials. However, I'd now like to have the wave functions react to the electric potential due to a 2D charge distribution.

The Poisson equation relates the potential with a charge distribution (I'm ignoring possible constants here since I'm not interested in actual units)

$\nabla^2 V = -\rho$.

If we take the Fourier transform we get

$-k^2 \hat{V} = -\hat{\rho} \Longleftrightarrow \hat{V} = \hat{\rho}/k^2$.

I'm well aware that at the origin $k^2 = 0$ and that the zero mode corresponds to the average value of $V$. Normally I'd just set $\hat{\rho}/k^2$ to zero there since the absolute value of the potential doesn't matter in most cases - it's its derivatives that appear in the equations.

Now, however, as far as I understand, in the Schrödinger equation we have

$\left(-\nabla^2 + V\right)\psi$,

meaning that it is actually the potential, not its derivatives, that shows up in the equation. How do I work out the proper value for $\hat{\rho}/k^2$ at the origin? Is it somehow related to the total charge in the system? My plan B is to solve $V$ using Jacobi over-relaxation, but I'd really like to stick with FFTs that are very efficient and noniterative.

I tried searching for previous questions and their answers here and elsewhere but couldn't find the answer I was looking for (or possibly identify one as such). Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ket[1]{|#1\rangle}$The absolute part of $V$ is *still* irrelevant in the Schrödinger equation. If you have an initial state $\ket\psi,$ then its time evolution is $$\ket{\psi(t)}=\exp(-iHt/\hbar)\ket\psi=\exp(-i(-\nabla^2+V)t/\hbar)\ket\psi.$$ If you add a constant to $V,$ so $V\mapsto V+E$ (equivalently, add a constant to $H$ for $H\mapsto H+E$), then the new time evolution is just (remember $\exp(A+B)=\exp A\exp B$ when $A,B$ commute) $$\ket{\psi'(t)}=\exp(-iEt/\hbar)\ket{\psi(t)}.$$ Now remember that quantum states are only physical up to global phases: $\ket\psi$ and $e^{i\theta}\ket\psi$ always represent the same physical situation. In particular, all observables (Hermitian operators) have the same probability distributions. So at every time $t,$ the evolved state with the shifted potential $\ket{\psi'(t)}$ is the *same physical state* as the state resulting from the unshifted potential $\ket{\psi(t)}$: *the absolute values of $V$ do not matter,* even for the Schrödinger equation.

So the reason you didn't find many answers to your question is because there's no question *to* answer. You can do whatever is most convenient for handling the 0-frequency component of $V$ and you will still get all the right physics.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! But isn't $\theta$ a function of $t$ then? Won't that mean that the phase varies faster and the wave function has more momentum? What if I were to couple multiple wave functions together via their electric potentials (the potential for each wave function is a sum of those of all the others)? The charge distribution of each wave function could be $c \left| \psi \right|^2$ where $c$ is a constant specific to each wave function and integrating the norm over the entire system yields 1. I'd imagine I'd need at least a consistent way of handling the zero modes?

Comment: The momentum ($\hat p=-i\hbar\nabla$) no longer involves a time-derivative in QM. The distribution of *any observable* at a time $t$ depends only on the wavefunction *at* time $t.$ I'm not sure what you're doing with the coupled system. Without approximations, for $n$ coupled particles there is *one* wavefunction *in $n$ variables.* E.g. for two coupled particles you have a wavefunction $\psi(t,x_1,x_2)$ satisfying $i\hbar\frac{d[\psi(t,x_1,x_2)]}{dt}=(-k_1{\nabla_{x_1}}^2-k_2{\nabla_{x_2}}^2+kq_1q_2/|x_1-x_2|+q_1V(x_1)+q_2V(x_2))\psi(t,x_1,x_2).$ Shift $V$ by a constant and nothing happens.

Comment: To be honest I'm not sure what I'm doing either but thanks again for the explanation. I assume the $k$'s are constants and the Laplacians are only with respect to the variables in their subscripts? Are the $V$'s particle-specific external potentials and the middle term gives the electric potential between the particles?

Comment: I was thinking of simulating $n$ wave functions for $n$ particles (again omitting constants for brevity/laziness): $i\partial\psi_i/\partial t=\left(-\nabla^2+\sum_{j\neq i}q_i q_j V_j \right)\psi_i$ where $V_j$ is given by the charge distribution $\rho_j$, which again is given by $c \left|\psi_j\right|^2$. This seems to give me something like particles bouncing off each other so that's quite promising. This might be completely wrong of course. I'm a bit confused how to interpret an $n$-dimensional wavefunction for $n$ particles when my system is 2-dimensional for any number of particles.

Comment: It only makes physical sense to have *one* external potential $V,$ shared between all particles! Otherwise you've interpreted me correctly. For $d$-dimensional space, the wavefunction of $n$ particles is a function of $n$ $d$-dimensional positions, for a total of $nd$ real inputs. *Rarely,* the particles will not be entangled and the wavefunction may separate as $\psi(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\psi_1(x_1)\ldots\psi_n(x_n),$ but the presence of interactions means this kind of state should not last. Your method of simulation *may* get some qualitative details right but I don't think it can be correct.

Comment: @PetriHirvonen As an example of something I think your method would get "completely" wrong: in 1 spatial dimension, start two particles of the same mass and charge in zero external field with the same one-particle wavefunction: a 0-centered Gaussian $\psi_i(x)\propto\exp(-x^2).$ This system is symmetric, and as it evolves the expected/average position of both particles is always zero. Yet the expected/average distance between them should grow with time, because the positions become correlated: each particle has a 50/50 chance of going left or right but they always go opposite ways.

Comment: As far as I understand, this seems to make sense, although I'm not sure if I know how I'd implement the solver for the single wave function in multiple variables. I might need to do some studying first. On the other hand I also have to think if I actually want to simulate the "real thing" - I just want to write an interactive toy program to play with that simulates some kind of probability waves interacting with each other and with external potentials. I don't really have any quantum mechanical problems that I'd need to simulate. But thanks again for the answer and the helpful comments!